# How to export an named instance in Vue.js, stop using: var app = this

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using .vue templates within a vue-cli created webpack project.

I typically use "export default" to export files, like this:

```
 export default {
   data () {
     return {
       message:''
     };
 },
 ...
```

Later in the script, when I try to access the instance, it seems within any function or third party library like axios, I have to write something like this at the top:

```
 var app = this;
```

so I can access data properties...for example:

```
    var app = this;

    axios.post('https://test.com/api/getMessage',{}).then(res => {
        app.message = res.data.message
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

But calling var app = this; all the time gets really tiresome.

I would prefer to put the instance in a variable like:

```
 let app = {
  data () {
    return {
       message:''
  };
 },
 methods :{
   getMessage:function(){

        axios.post('https://test.com/api/getMessage',{}).then(res => {
            app.message = res.data.message
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
   } 
 }  
}
```

But I don't understand how to export or import it properly. It seems every example just uses export default. So to restate my question, is there better /smarter way to export and import the script so I don't have to write:

```
 var app = this;
```

Comment: Just use `this` in your callbacks instead of app.

Comment: I've tried that, such as this.message = response.data.message but for some reason it breaks within the callback

Comment: Then something you haven't posted is wrong. If your code is what you posted at the end there, eliminating app, then `this` will be the Vue due to the arrow function.

Comment: Even assuming you're right that I could use `this.message`,  what could I do if I prefer to use `app.message` ?  Is there a better way than having to write `var app = this` in every method?

Comment: Using `app` in fashion you describe won't work in components. In this case, `app` refers to a single object, which you *could* potentially export. But that object is something used to *create* a component, it is *not* the component itself. Sometimes you will see what you describe when people create a Vue (`const app = new Vue(...)`), but it's a hack and a bad practice caused by not properly understanding how to refer to the Vue.

Answer (score 2):

```
axios.post('https://test.com/api/getMessage',{}).then(res => {
    this.message = res.data.message
})
```

That should work - Arrow functions take place in the scope in which they are written, meaning `this` will refer to your Vue instance there.  If you were not using arrow functions, you would have to specifically bind the scope:

```
axios.post('https://test.com/api/getMessage',{}).then(function(res){
    this.message = res.data.message
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thank you, that does help me understand why it was not working. I originally using the old function() syntax. However, I still would prefer to use `app.message` instead of `this.message` if possible. But I don't want to have to declare `var app = this` in each method. I'd prefer to call it at top when I create the component then be able to access it everywhere in the component.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Can you try it the way you have it in your second example, then use `export default app;` at the end?  I honestly enjoy using `this` as I come from Laravel and other object-oriented frameworks, so maybe if you use `this` for awhile you'll get used to it.  `this` is going to be used alllll over your component code so you might just try getting accustomed to that.

Comment: See `Test.vue` in this example please. As I explained above, it won't work with components. https://codesandbox.io/s/54jq2z0pvp

Comment: I did not know I could do something like `export default app`, that's very helpful. I'm sure using `this` is nice for many, but there must be an option for an alternative. Thank you